# jQuery and object literal function not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

i was trying to organize my jquery code so i created an object literal, but now the **focusTextArea** is not working and my textarea value is not updating.

Thanks for your help.

**html**

```
<textarea id="test"></textarea>​
```

---

**javascript**

```
(function($,window,document,undefined){

    var TEX = {

        inputField: $("textarea#test"),

        /* Init all functions */
        init: function()
        {
            this.focusTextArea();
        },

        /* Function update textarea */
        focusTextArea:  function()
        {
            this.inputField.text('test');
        },
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        TEX.init();
    });

})(jQuery,window,document);​
```

---

**jsfiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/vBvZ8/1/

Comment: seems to work fine if you include jQuery  http://jsfiddle.net/vBvZ8/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you haven't included jQuery correctly in the fiddle. Also, I *think* you mean to place the code in the `head` of the document (because of the `document.ready` handler).

More importantly perhaps the selector `$("textarea#test")` is run *before* the document is ready and therefore won't actually find the element correctly. I would recommend assigning `inputField` in `TEX.init`:

```
(function($,window,document,undefined){

    var TEX = {

        /* Init all functions */
        init: function()
        {
            this.inputField = $("#test");
            this.focusTextArea();
        },

        /* Function update textarea */
        focusTextArea:  function()
        {
            this.inputField.text('test');
        },
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        TEX.init();
    });

})(jQuery,window,document);​
```

**Updated example:** http://jsfiddle.net/xntA2/1/

As a side note, `textarea#test` should be changed to just `#test`. The `textarea` bit is superfluous since there should be only one element on the page with `id=test`.

Comment: assumption is incorrect since `jQuery` is argument of the self executing function...same wrapper used for all plugins

Comment: assumption that code is run before DOM ready...works fine  http://jsfiddle.net/vBvZ8/4/

Comment: Point taken--Although I assumed the OP meant to include all of his code in the `head` because of the `document.ready` handler. If you change the fiddle to use `nowrap (head)` (as would be more likely in an actual scenario) the code won't work. I'll update my answer though.

Comment: ok...  I guess it doesn't work exactly like a plugin... I did arbitrarily pick `no wrap body` in fiddle

Comment: other alternatives would be define function global rather than within self executing function, or define as plugin in `$.fn`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative syntax to avoid looking for an element before it exists is to return the element from a function:

```
(function($,window,document,undefined){

    var TEX = {
        /* function won't look for element until called*/
        inputField:function(){
            return $("textarea#test")
       }, 
        init: function()
        {
            this.focusTextArea();
        },
        focusTextArea:  function()
        {
            this.inputField().text('test');
        },
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        TEX.init();
    });

})(jQuery,window,document);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/vBvZ8/5/

I realize this is a simplified example...but you are also very close to creating a jQuery plugin and that may also be of benefit. Following provides same functionality as example:

```
(function($, window, document, undefined) {    
    $.fn.focusTextArea = function() {
        return this.each(function(){
            $(this).text('test');
        })        
    };    
})(jQuery, window, document);

$(function() {
    $('textarea').focusTextArea()
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/vBvZ8/8/

Comment: isn't that a little redundant, because every time you want to get a property you would have to query the DOM? Sorry I am new to all of this OOP stuff